# How to remove specific object from object array in localStorage

Tags: jscript

Can anybody advise me how I should go about adapting this code to remove the found object within an array of objects in localStorage.

So far everything I have tried results in either only the 1st object being removed or none at all.

I have tried using the following adaptations to the splice request, but it has not removed the selected object.

```
favorites.splice(favorites, [i]);
favorites.splice(favorites, 1);
favorites.splice(favorites, favorites[i]);
```

ect ect

I have also tried using the ifIncludes request but then again removing the individual object has been troublesome.

```
function checkfave (theid) {

    // get favorites from local storage or empty array
    var favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites')) || [];
    
    var theimage = $('#theimage'+theid).attr('src');
    var thetitle = $('#thetitle'+theid).text();
    var theprice = $('#theprice'+theid).text();
    
    var added=true;

        //Loop through the Favorites List and display in console (HIDDEN)
        console.clear();
        

        for (let i = 0; i < favorites.length; i++) {
            
            console.log(i)+'items added';
        
        
                    if ( favorites[i].ID == theid ) { 

                    var answer = window.confirm('You already Added To Your Favorites \r\r '+thetitle+' \r\r Do You Want To Remove It? '); 

                        if (answer) { // choose to remove

                            favorites.splice(favorites[i], [i]);

                            alert(thetitle+' \r\r Has Been Removed From Your Favorites \r\r At Position'+[i]);
                            
                            var added=false; break;     //IMPORTANT KILLS THE LOOP ONLY IF favorites[i].ID == theid
                            
                            }else {
                                   var added=false; break;
                                  }

                    }



        }//for loop


    if (added===true) {
        
        favorites.push({ID:theid,IMAGE:theimage,TITLE:thetitle,PRICE:theprice});
        
        localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites));
        
        alert('You Just Added To Your Favorites \r\r '+thetitle);
    }

console.log(localStorage.favorites);        

}//function
```

console log is returning in this format

```
favorites


    (2) [{…}, {…}]
    0
    : 
    {ID: 32921, IMAGE: 'uploads/posts/2017-07/1500056645_apulsoft-apqualizr-2.png',     TITLE: 'ApulSoft apQualizr 2 v2.5.2 ', PRICE: '19.99'}
    1
    : 
    {ID: 32920, IMAGE: 'uploads/posts/2022-03/1003229…cdj-lyrx-karaoke-player-software-for-mac-pc-1.png', TITLE: 'PCDJ LYRX v1.8.0.2 / v1.9.0.0 U2B ', PRICE: '19.99'}
length
    : 
    2
    [[Prototype]]
    : 
    Array(0)
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out on my own. Thanks

for (let i = 0; i < favorites.length; i++) {

```
            console.log(i)+'items added';
        
        
                    if ( favorites[i].ID == theid ) { 

                    var answer = window.confirm('You already Added To Your Favorites \r\r '+thetitle+' \r\r Do You Want To Remove It? '); 

                        if (answer) { // choose to remove
                            
                            
                            favorites.splice(i, 1);
                            localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites));
                            alert(thetitle+' \r\r Has Been Removed From Your Favorites \r\r At Position'+[i]);
                            
                            var added=false; break;     //IMPORTANT KILLS THE LOOP ONLY IF favorites[i].ID == theid
                            
                            }else {
                                   var added=false; break;
                                  }

                    }



        }//for loop
```

I was misunderstanding the nature of the splice function. i was trying to use favourites[i] = when favorites was already assumed in the 1st instance of the splice call.

I eventually came across the answer online in a similar situation.

the answer was to splice this way to remove at position i and remove 1 item

favorites.splice(i, 1);

Thanks anyway guys.